# Video.js won't play video on IE8

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-8, video.js

I'm trying to use Video.js 4.11 and after debugging I still couldn't make the video play in IE8 emulation. Strangely, video.js 4.12 version would cause a crash on IE8 emulation and it seems like there is a JSON problem involve the "data-set" tag?

Also, I noticed that even though I designed my own skin for video js, the "border-radius" is been override back to the default value while other things are working good. (my big play button should be a circle but in IE8 emulation, it became a square.)

Just to prove that it's not my video files' problem, I wrote a version based on the Video.js's example and using a lot of their codes but just changed slightly so the appearance would meet my needs.

Everything that I'm referencing locally, I have checked the path and they should be working fine.

Any suggestions and help would be highly appreciate.

**Update:**
  I solved the problem by adding this line of code:

```
<script src="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.6/html5media.min.js"></script>
```

Just in case someone had the same problem that their flash fallback is not working on IE8.

Here's my final code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
    <title>Video.js demo</title>  
    <link type="text/css" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://api.html5media.info/1.1.6/html5media.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
       .vjs-default-skin {color: #F5F2F2;}
       .vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button{left:45%;top:40%;border-radius:100%;border-width:0.1em;width:1.8em;height:1.8em;}
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
   <div style="width:700px;margin:0 auto;">     
    <video id="example" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
            controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
            poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
            data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' /> 
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
        <!-- Flash Fallback. -->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flowplayer-6.0.1/flowplayer.swf" width="854" height="504">
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            <param name="movie" value="flowplayer-6.0.1/MirandaS1E01.flv">
            <!--[if IE8]><param name="movie" value="flowplayer.swf"><![endif]-->
        </object>
        <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that 
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>            
    </video>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the problem with Internet Explorer 8, or the Internet Explorer 8 Document Mode (in a newer version of Internet Explorer)?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I believe it's in IE8 Document Mode because I'm using an IE11. I use the developer's tool to do the emulation so I would be able to see if it would work for IE8.

Comment: So I tested the code on IE8(not the document mode), it won't crash but the flash fall back is not working. The video can't be played.

Comment: Have you tried downloading flowplayer, and referencing it locally?

Comment: I have not. I'm trying to avoid reference anything locally as much as I possibly can because I need to send this to someone else and I need to make sure it would work for them as well. Thank you for your advice and keep helping me out. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I have tried referencing it locally but it still won't work.

Comment: Update: I found out that if I use video js 4.11 instead of 4.12, it won't crash on IE8 emulation. The problem of video not playing on IE8 emulation still exist though.